# Jquery Set Bound Model Property MVC

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, model

I couldn't find an answer to this issue so I'm posting some details on exactly what I'm trying to do. Should be basic stuff, but I can't get it work as expected.

I have a MVC view and related boolean model prop bound in the view as a hidden field.

On button click, I update the val of the hidden field. I can see the value is updated, however when I post the form, the value is still the original value which is false.

What am I missing here?

Sample code below:

```
<!--Auction Elements Click Handling -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#auctionFormatLink").click(function (event) {
            $("#IsBuyNowOnly").val('False');
            return false;
            e.preventDefault();
        });

        $("#buyNowOnlyFormatLink").click(function (event) {
            $("#IsBuyNowOnly").val('True');
            return false;
            e.preventDefault();
        });

    });
</script>

<div class="wrapsemibox">
    <div class="semiboxshadow text-center">
        <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Themes/calypso/img/shp.png")" class="img-responsive" alt="">
    </div>
    <section class="container">
            <div id="row">
                    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                        <h1 class="text-center smalltitle">
                            <span>Auction Editor</span>
                        </h1>
                        @using (Html.BeginForm("AuctionEditor", "Auction", FormMethod.Post, new { name = "frmAuctionEditor", id = "frmAuctionEditor" }))
                        { 
                            <div class="row">
                                     <div class="col-md-12">     
                                        <button class="btn btn-info btn-small" id="auctionFormatLink" />
                                        <button class="btn btn-small" id="buyNowOnlyFormatLink" />
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">    
                                    <input value="Cancel" type="submit" id="btnCancel" class="btn btn-gray btn-md">
                                    <input value="Preview Auction" type="submit" id="btnSaveChanges" class="btn btn-default btn-md">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        }
                    </div>
            </div>
    </section>
</div>
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.IsBuyNowOnly)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the input elements of Model properties that needs to be posted should be inside the form, otherwise default value of boolean (false) or the value set from get action is posted in model:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AuctionEditor", 
                       "Auction", 
                       FormMethod.Post, 
                       new { name = "frmAuctionEditor", id = "frmAuctionEditor" }))
       {
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.IsBuyNowOnly) 
        <div class="row">
             <div class="col-md-12">     
             <button class="btn btn-info btn-small" id="auctionFormatLink" />
             <button class="btn btn-small" id="buyNowOnlyFormatLink" />
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-12">    
          <input value="Cancel" type="submit" id="btnCancel" class="btn btn-gray btn-md">
         <input value="Preview Auction" type="submit" id="btnSaveChanges" class="btn btn-default btn-md">
          </div>
          </div>

       }
```

Comment: I knew it was something stupid, thanks for pointing it out :)